# Can I add custom UI Elements to UIActionSheet?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

I've successfully added Buttons to my UIActionSheet. I was wondering if I could add other elements, adjust the opacity, and alter the direction of the panel flying in (default comes in from below)with my UIActionSheet?

I am relatively new to iOS programming so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re going to customize it to that degree, you’re better off just creating your own custom overlay view and adding whatever controls you need to it. Adjusting the animation direction in particular would be more trouble than it’s worth.

For more information on custom views and the view hierarchy, plus a useful section on animations (see the sidebar), check out the [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW1).

Comment: with custom overlay, can i adjust the opacity levels?

Comment: Yup, just like any other property of a view. Use the `alpha` property. It, like many other properties on UIView, is animatable, so you can move the view while fading it in or out.

Answer (score 2):

Write implemention!

```
//.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UIImageActionSheet : UIActionSheet {
    UIImage *titleImage;
}
-(id) initWithImage:(UIImage *)image 
              title:(NSString *)title 
           delegate:(id <UIActionSheetDelegate>)delegate 
  cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle 
   destructiveButtonTitle:(NSString *)destructiveButtonTitle 
  otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles;
@end


//.m file
#import "UIImageActionSheet.h"

@implementation UIImageActionSheet
-(id) initWithImage:(UIImage *)image 
              title:(NSString *)title
           delegate:(id <UIActionSheetDelegate>)delegate 
  cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle 
destructiveButtonTitle:(NSString *)destructiveButtonTitle 
  otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles{

    self = [super initWithTitle:title delegate:delegate 
              cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle 
         destructiveButtonTitle:destructiveButtonTitle 
              otherButtonTitles:otherButtonTitles,nil];

if (self) {
    titleImage=image;
    [titleImage retain];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:titleImage];
    imageView.frame = CGRectZero;         
        for (UIView *subView in self.subviews){
            if (![subView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                [self insertSubview:imageView aboveSubview:subView];
                break;
            }
        }

        [imageView release];
    }
    return self;
}


- (CGFloat) maxLabelYCoordinate {
// Determine maximum y-coordinate of labels
CGFloat maxY = 0;
for( UIView *view in self.subviews ){
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        CGRect viewFrame = [view frame];
        CGFloat lowerY = viewFrame.origin.y + viewFrame.size.height;
        if(lowerY > maxY)
            maxY = lowerY;
    }
}
return maxY;
}

-(void) layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect frame = [self frame];
    CGFloat labelMaxY = [self maxLabelYCoordinate];

    for(UIView *view in self.subviews){
        if (![view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {    
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
                CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake((320 - titleImage.size.width)/2, labelMaxY + 10,
                                              titleImage.size.width, titleImage.size.height);
                [view setFrame:viewFrame];
            } 
            else if(![view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                CGRect viewFrame = [view frame];
                viewFrame.origin.y += titleImage.size.height+10;
                [view setFrame:viewFrame];
            }
        }
    }

    frame.origin.y -= titleImage.size.height + 2.0;
    frame.size.height += titleImage.size.height + 2.0;
    [self setFrame:frame];

}
/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code.
}
*/

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    if (titleImage) {
        [titleImage release];
    }
}


@end
```

Comment: So, that's a bunch of code. How does it answer the poster's question ?

Comment: addsubview is not available. write a new class extend it

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a custom overlay